# Button text color in Extjs 4

Tags: css, button, extjs, extjs4

I'm using [Exjts 4](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/) and i want to change the button text color. Here is my code:

```
{
     xtype: 'button',
     text: 'My Button',
     style:{
         color: 'red'
     }  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some strange behavior in [Extjs 4.2.0](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/), but there is an override possible. Give your `button` a `class` using `cls:'yourClassName'` property and then in CSS make a full path to `span` holding the text, like so: `.yourClassName div a span`. Also give your css property a [!important](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) value to successfuly override base class.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {

    text: 'Click me',

    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    handler: function() {
        alert('You clicked the button!');
    },

    cls: 'foo'
});
```

and in css simply:

```
.foo div a span
{
    color:#ff0000 !important;
}
```

### Here is a [example](http://jsfiddle.net/YuV7m/3/).

Answer (score 7):

In case someone needs it. I do not know if it's a dirty solution but it works

```
{
 xtype: 'button',
 text: '<div style="color: red">My Button</div>',     
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Davor Zubak shed light on a solution although it failed in my complex application. I achieved what I want by this:

1. Button's cls: 'myButton'
2. In my css file, define:

   ```
   .myButton .x-btn-inner {
       color: red;
       font-family: Georgia;
       font-size: large;
       font-weight: bold;
   }
   ```

This way it only overrides the ExtJS theme for the particular buttons who have 'myButton' cls.