# Why don't the button letters change color?

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
new Ext.Button({
    text: 'testing'
    ,style: {
       'background-color': 'blue',
       'color': 'red',
       'margin-right' : '15px'
   }
    ,handler : function() {
        window.open("https://www.google.es");
    }
})
```

I'm putting in the style 'color': 'red', but the letter is still black and does not change color. Anyone have any idea why ..?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201401/button-text-color-in-extjs-4

Comment: Yeah it's works , with that link

Answer (score 0):

In case someone need..that's my solution:

```
new Ext.Button({
    text: '<div style="color: white">testing</div>'
    ,style: {
       'background-color': '#0099ff',
       'border-radius': '5px',
       'padding-left': '5px',
       'padding-right': '5px',
       'padding-top': '1px',
       'padding-bottom': '1px'
   }
    ,handler : function() {
        window.open("https://www.google.es");
    }
})
```

Comment: Better to use styling: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/guides/components/grids/layouts_styling.html

Comment: im not using 7.2 , but thank you , i will keep an eye